# postgres: how to add 2 'time without timezone' columns?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to add 2 'time without timezone' columns in postgres. What is the best way to achieve or correct this?

```
SELECT time_of_day + offset_time
FROM event_time;
```

> "Error: operator is not unique: time without time zone + time without time zone. HINT:  Could not choose a best candidate operator. You might need to add explicit type casts. SQL state: 42725".

Comment: You don't.  You add an interval to a timestamp.

Comment: A `time` is a "point in time". Adding "*8 in the morning*" to "*10 in the evening*" doesn't really make sense.

Comment: In other words: change the data type of `offset_time` to `interval`.

Answer (score 3):

What is happening:

```
select '11:34'::time + '1:00'::time;
ERROR:  operator is not unique: time without time zone + time without time zone
LINE 1: select '11:34'::time + '1:00'::time;
```

Per Gordon Linoffs comment, what you need to do:

```
select '11:34'::time + '1:00'::interval;
 ?column? 
----------
 12:34:00
```

Per docs [Date/Time Operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-datetime.html) you can subtract times, but you can't add them. You can only add an `interval` to a time.